# Write the set of all positive integers in triangular array as

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> 1 3 6 10 15 . .
> 2 5 9 14 .  . .
> 4 8 13 . .  . .
> 7 12  . . . . .
> 11
>
> Find the row number and column number where 20096 occurs. For example 8 appears in the third row and second column.

Source: [ISI entrance exam 2016 sample questions](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's look how would I get it.

First, we can determine the id of the anti-diagonal, denoted by $n$ at which a value $X$ would be by using the following trick:

1. The number of all elements to left of this anti-diagonal $n$ is a sum of arithmetic series, hence, $S_{n} = n(n-1)/2$.
2. We know that $X$ belongs to anti-diagonal $n$ and $S_n>S_{n-1}$. Hence, we solve the equation $S_n = X$ to get $n$ as follows:
   $$
   n(n-1)/2=X \rightarrow n = \left\lceil\frac{\sqrt{8X-1}-1}{2}\right\rceil
   $$
3. For this anti diagonal elements, $i+j=n+1$ and the first element (at $i = n$ and $j=1$) is $A = 1+n(n-1)/2$.
4. Let $d = X-A$, then the position of $X$ is: $i=n-d$ and $j=1+d$.

**For your $X=20096$, Here are the steps:**

- $$
  n = \left\lceil\frac{\sqrt{8X-1}-1}{2}\right\rceil = 200
  $$
- $A = 1+n(n-1)/2 = 19901$.
- $d = X-A = 195$, then the position of $X$ is: $i=5$ and $j=196$.

**If interested:** I have tried this code in MATLAB and it is working like a charm:

X=20096;

A=1:X;

n=ceil(0.5*(sqrt(8*X+1)-1));

for idx=1:n-1

A = A(idx+1:end); %remove elements anti-diagonal by anti-diagonal

end

d = length(A)-1;

ii = n-d

jj = d+1